# The Saves button is not always shown active when it should be which leads to error when using it

Tags: bug, user-interface, saves

Easy steps to reproduce:

1. Go to any review queue.
2. Open the post in a new tab and click the Save button.
3. Go to the tab with the review and refresh the page. The Save button will show as inactive.
4. Click the Save button in the review. This will always show an error.

[See demonstration here as GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFcwR.gif)

Essentially, the problem is if you have a post already saved. The above steps are a way to simulate that in an easy fashion, hence the artificial steps of extra saving. But the same would happen if you encounter any post you have already saved.

The problem is that in some of the views the save state of the post is not taken into account for the Save button. Thus when clicking it it makes a request to the `/posts/<post id>/save` endpoint (with no extra query parameters) and the response back is `{"ErrorMessage":"isUndo parameter is misaligned with post's save status."}`

What seems to be affected is all reviews and the duplicate closure dialog. NOTE: **DO NOT TRY TO USE THE SAVE BUTTON FROM THE DUPLICATE CLOSURE DIALOG UNTIL [THIS BUG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421260/if-i-close-question-a-with-question-b-and-b-has-an-answer-from-me-or-if-i-linked) IS FIXED!** (I cannot emphasise this enough). When the bug is removed, the same problem can be observed there: [see demonstration with duplicates as GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1t9Q.gif).

Comment: Can repro. But I'm not sure what the fix should be: (a) simply hide the save icon from those views, (b) show the icon but make it read only, (c) make it work exactly like the main question page. If (c) is significant work I think it's reasonable to concede that all functionality doesn't necessarily have to be present in those places, and therefore (a) or (b) would be acceptable.

Comment: @AaronBertrand (a) seems reasonable. Inside the dupe dialog the voting buttons are already missing. And I'm pretty sure the Bookmark button wasn't there, either. It would be more consistent. For reviews, I guess is acceptable to just require going to the original post to Save it. (b) is a no-go IMO. It requires the button to be rendered correctly, otherwise the read-only doesn't make sense. And if it's rendered correctly that's just (c), no read-only needed. The button works as long as its initial state matches the actual state it should be. I.e., unsaved question with unsaved button is OK.

Comment: Is this [[tag:status-complete]] now? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421376